# Setting style attribute to none for every table tr and td elements inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with id testdiv. Inside the div i have a table with no id or class . I would like to set the style attribute of all table tr and td elements inside the div to none. 
How can this be done using jquery code. Some example code would be really appreciated

Please Help.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/), like this:

```
$("#testdiv").find("table, tr, td").removeAttr("style");
```

Note though this just removes **inline** styles, whatever's defined in your stylesheets will still apply.

From a more general standpoint, an ID is never needed to select an element, you can just use an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) like I have in the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) call above, so for example this code looks for all `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` elements that are descendants of that `<div id="testdiv">`.