# find() function not working on page load in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery code to remove the style attribute of all `table`, `tr` and `td` elements located inside a `div` with `id="testdiv"`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testdiv").find("table, tr, td").removeAttr("style");
});
```

If i run the `$("#testdiv").find("table, tr, td").removeAttr("style");` line in the firebug console directly it works,but its not working automatically when the page loads.
How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Are the elements added after page load?  Also don't create multiple accounts, and please accept answers if they resolve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193398/setting-style-attribute-to-none-for-every-table-tr-and-td-elements-inside-a-div-u

Comment: If you have the HTML rendered at the page load then the code should work. If the content is loaded at a later time then this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick. I guess the elements are being added after page load.Any way to make it work in that case ?. Thanks

Comment: @John - When are they being added?

Comment: @John: You *guess*? Is it your code?

Comment: @Nick Im using the Gauge gadget of the Google Visualization API (http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/gauge.html). So i think the elements are generated as result of some ajax call.

Comment: so I suppose you need to run that code inside the callback  google.setOnLoadCallback(...)

Answer (score 1):

you need to run that code inside the callback google.setOnLoadCallback(...)